# check if element in list of lists ionic 3

Tags: ionic3

I have this list :

```
list1 = [['phone1','123'],['phone2','125'],...]
```

I want to check if a variable x is in the list 
for example when x == '123' it'a not pushed to `list1` .

I tried this code but I'm failing to get it :

```
const phone = this.eForm.value['phone'];
const name= this.eForm.value['name'];
for (let i = 0; i < list1.length; i++) {
      if (list1[i][1] == phone) {
        list1.push([name, phone]);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will search the 2D array you noted and allow you to search it using `find()`.  Check [docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

```js
let list1 = [
  ['phone1', '123'],
  ['phone2', '125']
];

let phone = '123';
let phoneName = 'phone3';

//Find() method will search each item of the array and return the result
let foundResult = list1.find((listItem) => {
  return listItem[1] === phone
});

//Find() method will search each item of the array and return the result.  This one will not find a match.
let notFoundResult = list1.find((listItem) => {
  return listItem[1] === '555-555-5555'
});

console.log(`First Output: ${(foundResult) ? 'Found Something!' : 'Nope'}`);
console.log(`Second Output: ${ (notFoundResult) ? 'Found Something!' : 'Nope'}`);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot  :))))

Answer (score 1):

```
let list1 = [['phone1','123'],['phone2','125']];

const phone = 'phone3';

if(list1.reduce((n, element) => { return n + (element[0] == phone) }, 0) > 0)
{
console.log("phone3 exists in list1");
}
else
{
console.log("phone3 is not anywhere in list1");
}
```

The value returned from the reduce function represents how many times 'phone3' is present in your list1 array.

Therefore, if it is greater than 0 'phone3' exists.